# Why is there a maximum time for length of write pulse to write on an EEPROM?

Tags: datasheet, eeprom, timing

I am still just learning about electronics on my own, so please bear with me.

The EEPROMs that I have come across ([for example this one](http://cva.stanford.edu/classes/cs99s/datasheets/at28c16.pdf) where the t_wp max is 1000 ns.) all have a time limit for the write pulse (I think this is called the Write Pulse Width). I am just curious, but

1) What is the reason that EEPROMS have this upper limit?

2) Are there any parallel EEPORMs with no upper time limit?

Please note that I am not asking about the limit on the number of times one can write to an EEPROM.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are two reasons I can think of for having a limit to the write pulse length:

1. If the part uses dynamic latches to hold the address, those latches may only be able to hold their value for a certain length of time.  Since the address is latched on the falling edge of /CE & /WE, but the write doesn't start until the rising edge, giving the chip a write command that's long relative to the time required to complete a write cycle could result in the dynamic latches forgetting the address before the write cycle is complete.
2. If the device rejects any write cycles that are excessively long, that may help guard against erroneous write operations in cases where a system operation gets disrupted (e.g. by loss of power).  If that were the intended purpose, however, I would expect a specification that would indicate that write pulses within a certain range are guaranteed to be accepted, write pulses that are outside a larger range would be guaranteed to be ignored, and those between the two ranges might arbitrarily be accepted or ignored.

In either case, 1000ns seems like a curiously short maximum.  The address needs to be held for an entire write cycle, so any dynamic latches would need to be able to deal with that.  If the cycle limit is intended to guard against stray write events, engineering it to be usable with systems that run at slow clock speeds should have been trivial and would have improved usability.

Answer (score 9):

I assume your question relates to parallel EEPROMs.

The Write pulse (time) is a minimum specification and typically has no upper bound. In other words the time specified limits the speed of writing (bits/bytes/words per second), but the chips will operate at any lower write rate.

For example here is the [datasheet](http://ww1.microchip.com/downloads/en/DeviceDoc/doc0270.pdf) for the 26C64 write timing:

[image]

Notice there is no upper bound for any of the chip select or write timing.

Addition:

The 28C16 you raised in the comments shows a limitation of the early EEPROMs ...they needed a higher write voltage for the cell write/erase cycle.
This meant they could not work down to DC (the lowest freq of write cycle possible).

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the answer. An example that I have worked with is this one http://cva.stanford.edu/classes/cs99s/datasheets/at28c16.pdf

Comment: Good answer. For "...they needed a higher write voltage for the cell write/erase cycle. This meant they could not work down to DC.", I realised what you mean but other readers may not, may think DC's something about the write voltage. Would be good to clarify by changing the DC bit. Thanks, Jack.

Comment: The 1us maximum write pulse time seems really weird, since many processors would need extra circuitry in order to meet that spec.  An 1802 running at 3.58Mhz/2, for example, would assert its write signal for 1.11us.  And of course processors running off watch crystals would likely assert /WE for dozens of microseconds.

Answer (score 1):

> ## CHIP CLEAR
>
> The contents of the entire memory of the AT28C16 may be set to the high state by the CHIP CLEAR operation. By setting CE low and OE to 12 volts, the chip is cleared when a 10 msec low pulse is applied to WE.

So if the write pulse is too long, you clear the chip.

Comment: Since applying 12 V to the *OE is a special condition (Erase Cycle) it has nothing to do with normal writes to the EEPROM and can't possibly be confused or impact the write cycle.